# Breakout game ( When im out, i want the ball again to hit the remaining bricks)

Tags: java, paint, breakout

Im new to java programming. Im learning to develop a game similar to the one called breakout. Here's how it works

> you have a set of bricks to hit using a ball and the paddle

Im caught in a situation here,

Whenever i miss the ball, itl take me to the else loop where im sending "Game over" message.
Instead i want the ball back again, and the other left over bricks to hit.

Here's the snippet
Java Code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
       super.paint(g);

       if (ingame) {
           g.drawImage(ball.getImage(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),
                       ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight(), this);
           g.drawImage(paddle.getImage(), paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(),
                       paddle.getWidth(), paddle.getHeight(), this);

           for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
               if (!bricks[i].isDestroyed())
                   g.drawImage(bricks[i].getImage(), bricks[i].getX(),
                               bricks[i].getY(), bricks[i].getWidth(),
                               bricks[i].getHeight(), this);
           }
       } else {

           Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 18);
           FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(font);

           g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
           g.setFont(font);
           g.drawString(message,
                        (Commons.WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(message)) / 2,
                        Commons.WIDTH / 2);
       }


       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
       g.dispose();
   }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @DanielA.White It's a programming question too, so it's on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use paintComponent()

2) Don't destry the Graphics passed as argument

3) The code should be equal to the start code; move the ball inside the playfield and start again.

Comment: But how do i get those bricks from the previous state?
Something to do with the for loop... please help

Comment: You haven't deleted them? Why should they vanish?

Comment: Here is the requirement!
Suppose i have 5 bricks to hit, I take my first shot and hit a brick, it vanishes, there remains other 4 bricks, i miss the ball for my second shot.
now i want the ball and the paddle and the remaining 4 bricks, so that i can resume playing

Comment: isDestroyed() consists of a boolean value false. Doen't it delete the brick??

Comment: Some where in the code; ingame is set to false. You have to find this location and reset the balls position.